# Laravel 5.5 - arvore de categorias

Tags: php, laravel, relacionamento

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de uma tabela "categories":

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('main_category');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Em minha model fiz a seguinte função:

```
public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'main_category','id');
}
```

Em minha controller está desta maneira:

```
public function index()
{
    $tree_categories = Category::where('main_category', '0')->with('subCategories')->get();
    return $tree_categories;
}
```

Essa função busca as categorias consideradas "mães", este retorno fica desta maneira:

```
 [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "main_category": 0,
      "name": "Oleos",
      "description": "teste",
      "created_at": "2017-09-30 01:30:30",
      "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
      "sub_categories": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "main_category": 5,
          "name": "Fluidos",
          "description": "Teste",
          "created_at": "2017-09-30 01:30:30",
          "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Minha view exemplo:

```
@extends('layouts.template')

@section('content')

<div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="ls-label">
        <b class="ls-label-text">Categorias</b>
        <div class="ls-custom-select ls-field-md">
            <select name="id" id="id" class="ls-select">
                <option value="" selected="selected">TODOS</option>
                @foreach($tree_categories as $tree_category)
                <option value="{{$tree_category['id']}}" data-type="main">{{$tree_category['name']}}</option>
                @if(count($tree_category['sub_categories']) > 0)
                    @foreach($tree_category['sub_categories'] as $sub_category)
                        <option value="{{$sub_category['id']}}" data-type="sub">{{$sub_category['name']}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

@endsection
```

Meus dados no banco:
[image: dados banco]

Retorno página HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="ls-label">
        <b class="ls-label-text">Categorias</b>
        <div class="ls-custom-select ls-field-md">
            <select name="id" id="id" class="ls-select">
                <option value="" selected="selected">TODOS</option>
                <option value="1" data-type="main">Categoria indefinida</option>
                <option value="2" data-type="main">INTERRUPTOR OLEO </option>
                <option value="3" data-type="main">FERRAMENTAS EM GERAL</option>
                <option value="4" data-type="main">Oléo</option>
                <option value="5" data-type="main">Oleos</option>
                <option value="7" data-type="main">BOMBAS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Assim faço um foreach neste retorno em minha view, se acessando a $var['id'] obtenho o id retornado, porem ao acessar $var['sub_categories'] o retorno é null, tentei de várias formas obter esses valores porem sem sucesso. Existe algo que deveria fazer devido a forma que foi gerado essa informação? Como consigo obter os valores de sub_categories?

Comment: Coloque a `View` !!! porque `sub_categories` é um `array`!

Comment: inseri na pergunta

Comment: Isso acontece uma vez só ou em todo a listagem??? olhando assim não consegui pegar o erro.

Comment: em toda a listagem, apenas é "impresso" as categorias consideradas "principais", não entra no laço das subs, vendo o retorno dos dados, não vejo problema em não conseguir acessar esse valor, até pq tenho outros retornos semelhantes e acesso normalmente conforme está na minha view, porem este ai não consigo acessar essa info

Comment: Se tem como colocar o resultado final? tipo o html produzido.?

Comment: inseri os dados do banco e o retorno html

Comment: Poxa agora que vi um troço estranho no seu controller está só um retorno assim: `return $tree_categories;`????

Comment: sim, nesse retorno vem todos os dados da tabela ja com as subs indicada, eu coloquei apenas um dado na pergunta como exemplo, mas no retorno vem todos corretamente, o problema é apenas acessar essa informação para exibi-la na view

Comment: Para mim te falar qualquer coisa teria que passar um pente fino, porque, imagine você dados desencontrados, código teóricamente correto, mas, agora vi um troço estranho no retorno então pode ser tanta coisa ... !!! é complicado dizer se ver um a parte maior.

Comment: entendo, agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Consegui resolver kkkk, a forma correta de acessar essa informação seria:
$variavel->subCategories

vendo o array inteiro, o nome é apresentado de outra forma, que era a que eu tentava acessar, porem deve-se acessar via funcao de relacionamento